Windows 10 Magnifier - Does zooming cause pixilation loss while super sampled
When we use Windows Magnifier we can choose a zoom level that will show certain areas of screen in larger scale (zoomed in). When this happens, normally we lose pixel resolution on our screens, because zoom isn't upscaling the content of the screen, or providing more pixels, as it is simply zooming in.

On my 1080p TV that I use for a monitor, I can watch videos that are 2160p, but I will never see this many pixels because my monitor can only output 1080p. What I want to know is if I am watching a 2160p video, and use the Windows Magnifier, will I still be losing pixel data within a certain zoom level (say 200 - 300 zoom level) or does magnifier calculate the amount of pixels being shown and interpolate the data?
To be clear, I am not asking if I will ever see more than 1080 pixels on my screen. I want to know if Windows knows that there are 2160 pixels being shown, and if it is still drawing those pixels, and whether the Magnifier tool interpolates those pixels while zooming.
